# In robot framework is there a method to print the variable value of the embedded argument in keyword rather than the variable name?

Tags: robotframework

```
*** keywords ***
Do something on ${var1} and ${var2}
    Log ${var1} 
    Log ${var2}

*** Test Cases ***
Testing
    ${id1}  Set Variable    variable1
    ${id2}  Set Variable    variable2
    Do something on ${id1} and ${id2}
```

When we run the above robot testcase the logs display ${id1} and ${id2} as variables in the keyword.

```
KEYWORD ${id1} = BuiltIn . Set Variable variable1
KEYWORD ${id2} = BuiltIn . Set Variable variable2
KEYWORD Do something on ${id1} and ${id2}
```

Is it possible in robot to have the log print the value of the variable instead of the variable itself in such use case, where the embedded arguments are variables?

For example can we have log print

```
KEYWORD Do something on variable1 and variable2
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes its worthy to read the official documentation.

`Log To Console` - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console

Also, you have `Log ${var1}` and it should be `Log  ${var1}` (more than one space acts as separator)

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the question. I think it is  about that when an embedded arged keyword gets logged the log shows the name of the arg and not its value.

Comment: Yes you are right @BenceKaulics that is indeed the question.